# Building a M1 Finance pie type UI on Google Sheets! Any suggestions?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So I already have a dividend income portfolio spreadsheet that I built but I wanted to add another tab to it, that sort of helps me create my pie with the same UI as M1 Finance [image: Example of the M1 Finance Pie]
Wanted to see, if anyone has built anything like this or have any suggestions to get started?

Comment: check reddit for this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Google Apps Script to [deploy a web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) that makes use of the spreadsheet data and Google Charts to build a dashboard. See https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls